# How to fetch data before mounting the root Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

**TL;DR:** What is a good way to do async stuff before starting the app?
 vue-devtools does not work correctly if I wait for async stuff to finish before creating / mounting the root Vue instance.

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm developping a back office app where nothing is accessible unless the user is logged. Except for the sign in / sign up pages of course.

So on page load I do something like this:

```
// Set up store and router ...

router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) { 
    /* redirect to auth if store.state.auth.isLogged is false */ 
}

// Dispatch an action that send a request to the API to get the connected user 
// (or null if the user is not logged) 
store.dispatch('getAuth').then(user) {
    // Mount the app one the request is done and the mutation for isLogged is done
    new Vue({
        el: '#app', 
        router,
        store,
        // ...
    });
}
```

And in my index.html I have a pure HTML/CSS loading page that waits for the vue app to mount.

So this works fine, on load, the app check if the user is logged and once this is done, it redirects to the auth pag if needed.

My problem is mainly with vue-devtools, it seems that if the root Vue instance is not mounted on page load, I can't inspect components from the vue-devtools, but the vuex & events inspection works. Plus the extension icon on chrome is grayed out ("Vue.js not detected") whereas it kind of works.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a problem with the devtools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. There is a refresh button at the top right of the Vue dev tools. Click it and your asynchronously loaded Vue instance should be detected.